# Camel Route for Javamail Not Stopping on Shutdown

Tags: apache-camel, jakarta-mail, quartz-scheduler

I've a simple route

```
 from(
            "myQuartz://EMAIL_Route?cron=0+0/5+*+*+*+?")
            .routeId("EMAIL_Route")
            .shutdownRunningTask(
                    ShutdownRunningTask.CompleteCurrentTaskOnly)
            .beanRef("errorReportProcessor")
            .filter((body().isNotNull()))
            .to("smtp://smtpHost?From=someone&to=someoneElse&Subject=something").end();
```

Even if I shutdown the application in Websphere application server, I still continue to get emails. The scheduler/thread is not stopping. In my quartz properties file, I also tried

```
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon=true
```

but, fruitless. The Camel, Quartz and Mail component version is 2.12.4. Spring 3.2.5.Release. Websphere 8.

SystemOut.log files clearly mentions, the application stopped without errors. However, I can see a java.exe instance running in task-manager.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found the issue was with missing "root-app-context". Once, I configured the "root-app-context", the Cron-scheduler is now stopping and no more stranded threads. :)

Even the extra configuration to makeSchedulerThreadDaemon was not required.

```
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon=true
```